# Trying to Create a JavaScript Calculator for amps needed

Tags: javascript, calculator, nan

Hello I am trying to make a calculator so that people can tell how many watts, amps and voltage they will need on the job site. I am trying to make a form they can fill out that will allow them to put in how many of each type of device they have on the job site. I have everything the way I want it but when I hit calculate the reply is "NaN". I thank you for any help at all.

```html
<form><table width="960">
<tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>HD-CVI Cameras</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
 <tr><td>HAC-HDBW2220R-Z:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.7 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueOne"   value="0" id="valueOne"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>HAC-HFW2220R-Z:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.7 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwo"   value="0" id="valueTwo"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>DH-IDF-480B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueThree" value="0" id="valueThree"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IBF-680B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFour" value="0" id="valueFour"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IBV-780B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFive" value="0" id="valueFive"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IDV-580B(W)-MZ:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 1.0 Amps (/w Motorized Lens)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueSix" value="0" id="valueSix"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IDV-580B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentyfour" value="0" id="valueTwentyfour"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IDF-480B(W):</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.45 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueSeven" value="0" id="valueSeven"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IBF-680B(W):</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.45 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueEight" value="0" id="valueEight"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DH-IV-980W:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.45 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueNine" value="0" id="valueNine"> <br></td></tr>  
    <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>HD-CVI PTZ Cameras</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>SD42212I-HC:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTen" value="0" id="valueTen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>SD59220I-HC:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueEleven" value="0" id="valueEleven"> <br></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>Uniview IPC Cameras</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>IPC542E-DUC:</td><td>AC 24V / DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.60 Amps (When ICR Switches)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwelve" value="0" id="valueTwelve"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC3612ER3-PF28(36):</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; .47 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueThirteen" value="0" id="valueThirteen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC3232ER-VS(DV):</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.65 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFourteen" value="0" id="valueFourteen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC2122SR3-PF36:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.55 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFifteen" value="0" id="valueFifteen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC242E-IR-Z-IN:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.00 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueSixteen" value="0" id="valueSixteen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC242ER5-DL:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.00 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueEightteen" value="0" id="valueEightteen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC3234SR-DVZ28:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.50 Amps (/w Motorized Lens)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueNineteen" value="0" id="valueNineteen"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC2124SR3-PF36:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.55 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwenty" value="0" id="valueTwenty"> <br></td></tr>
    <tr><td>IPC2324EBR-DPZ28:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.50 Amps (/w Motorized Lens)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentyfive" value="0" id="valueTwentyfive"> <br></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>Uniview PTZ Cameras</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC642E-X30N:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentyone" value="0" id="valueTwentyone"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC6222ER-X20(X30):</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentytwo" value="0" id="valueTwentytwo"> <br></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>IPC6242SL-X22:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentythree" value="0" id="valueTwentythree"> <br></td></tr>
 
<tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td><div id="result"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"></td><td><input type="button" value="Calculate power needed!"  onclick="javascript:myCalc(document.getElementById('valueOne').value, document.getElementById('valueTwo').value, document.getElementById('valueThree').value, document.getElementById('valueFour').value), document.getElementById('valueFive').value, document.getElementById('valueSix').value, document.getElementById('valueSeven').value, document.getElementById('valueEight').value, document.getElementById('valueNine').value, document.getElementById('valueTen').value, document.getElementById('valueEleven').value, document.getElementById('valueTwelve').value, document.getElementById('valueThirteen').value, document.getElementById('valueFourteen').value, document.getElementById('valueFifteen').value, document.getElementById('valueSixteen').value, document.getElementById('valueSeventeen').value, document.getElementById('valueEightteen').value, document.getElementById('valueNineteen').value, document.getElementById('valueTwenty').value, document.getElementById('valueTwentyone').value, document.getElementById('valueTwentytwo').value, document.getElementById('valueTwentythree').value, document.getElementById('valueTwentyfour').value, document.getElementById('valueTwentyfive').value">
</form></td></tr>
    </table> 
<script>
 
function myCalc(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour ,valueFive, valueSix, valueSeven, valueEight, valueNine, valueTen, valueEleven, valueTwelve, valueThirteen, valueFourteen, valueFifteen, valueSixteen, valueSeventeen, valueEightteen, valueNineteen, valueTwenty, valueTwentyone, valueTwentytwo, valueTwentythree, valueTwentyfour, valueTwentyfive)
{
    if (valueOne == 0) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
    } else if (valueTwo == 0) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
    } else if (valueThree == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
    } else if (valueFour == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueFive == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueSix == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueSeven == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueEight == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueNine == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueEleven == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwelve == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueThirteen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueFourteen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueFifteen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueSixteen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueEightteen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueNineteen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwenty == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwentyone == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwentytwo == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwentythree == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwentyfour == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
 } else if (valueTwentyfive == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueSeventeen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyFour)*.50));
 } else if (valueSeventeen == 0)  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50));
  } else  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: '+ ((parseFloat(valueTwo)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueThree)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueOne)*.70) + (parseFloat(valueFive)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSix)*1.0) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfour)*.5) + (parseFloat(valueSeven)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueEight)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueNine)*.45) + (parseFloat(valueTwelve)*.60)+ (parseFloat(valueThirteen)*.47) +(parseFloat(valueFourteen)*.65) + (parseFloat(valueFifteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueSixteen)*1.00) + (parseFloat(valueFour)*.50) + (parseFloat(valueEightteen)*1.50) + (parseFloat(valueNineteen)*.55) + (parseFloat(valueTwentyfive)*1.50))  
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you thought about **all** the conditions/states of all of the 25 inputs? Does your code cover all of those conditions?

Comment: You should first consider refactoring this code so you have way less duplication. As you refactor and reduce the code you may find your error. And if you don't, you may make it easier for us to help you find the error.

Comment: I am not very good with coding scripts I actually found the main script here online and used it to make some other calculators that worked very well, when we saw a need for this calculator I tried to edit the main script to work this way. I am not sure on how to simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design makes me cry...  But here is the fixed(-up) solution...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table width="960">
            <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>HD-CVI Cameras</h2></td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>HAC-HDBW2220R-Z:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.7 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueOne" value="0" id="valueOne"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>HAC-HFW2220R-Z:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.7 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwo" value="0" id="valueTwo"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IDF-480B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueThree" value="0" id="valueThree"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IBF-680B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFour" value="0" id="valueFour"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IBV-780B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFive" value="0" id="valueFive"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IDV-580B(W)-MZ:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 1.0 Amps (/w Motorized Lens)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueSix" value="0" id="valueSix"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IDV-580B(W)(ZA)-V2:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.5 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentyfour" value="0" id="valueTwentyfour"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IDF-480B(W):</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.45 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueSeven" value="0" id="valueSeven"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IBF-680B(W):</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.45 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueEight" value="0" id="valueEight"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>DH-IV-980W:</td><td>DC 12V</td><td>&lt; 0.45 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueNine" value="0" id="valueNine"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>HD-CVI PTZ Cameras</h2></td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>SD42212I-HC:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTen" value="0" id="valueTen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>SD59220I-HC:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueEleven" value="0" id="valueEleven"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>Uniview IPC Cameras</h2></td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC542E-DUC:</td><td>AC 24V / DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.60 Amps (When ICR Switches)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwelve" value="0" id="valueTwelve"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC3612ER3-PF28(36):</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; .47 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueThirteen" value="0" id="valueThirteen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC3232ER-VS(DV):</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.65 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFourteen" value="0" id="valueFourteen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC2122SR3-PF36:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.55 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueFifteen" value="0" id="valueFifteen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC242E-IR-Z-IN:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.00 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueSixteen" value="0" id="valueSixteen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC242ER5-DL:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.00 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueEightteen" value="0" id="valueEightteen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC3234SR-DVZ28:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.50 Amps (/w Motorized Lens)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueNineteen" value="0" id="valueNineteen"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC2124SR3-PF36:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 0.55 Amps (When IRs cut on)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwenty" value="0" id="valueTwenty"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC2324EBR-DPZ28:</td><td>DC 12V / PoE</td><td>&lt; 1.50 Amps (/w Motorized Lens)</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentyfive" value="0" id="valueTwentyfive"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h2>Uniview PTZ Cameras</h2></td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Model</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Voltage type</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amps</b></td><td bgcolor="#eaeaea"><b>Amount on Job</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC642E-X30N:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentyone" value="0" id="valueTwentyone"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC6222ER-X20(X30):</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentytwo" value="0" id="valueTwentytwo"> <br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>IPC6242SL-X22:</td><td>AC 24V</td><td>3.0 Amps</td><td><input type="text" name="valueTwentythree" value="0" id="valueTwentythree"> <br></td></tr>

            <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="3"></td><td><div id="result"></div></td></tr>
            <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Calculate power needed!" onclick="javascript:myCalc();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>

        function myCalc() {
            var valueOne = document.getElementById('valueOne').value;
            var valueTwo = document.getElementById('valueTwo').value;
            var valueThree = document.getElementById('valueThree').value;
            var valueFour = document.getElementById('valueFour').value;
            var valueFive = document.getElementById('valueFive').value;
            var valueSix = document.getElementById('valueSix').value;
            var valueSeven = document.getElementById('valueSeven').value;
            var valueEight = document.getElementById('valueEight').value;
            var valueNine = document.getElementById('valueNine').value;
            var valueTen = document.getElementById('valueTen').value;
            var valueEleven = document.getElementById('valueEleven').value;
            var valueTwelve = document.getElementById('valueTwelve').value;
            var valueThirteen = document.getElementById('valueThirteen').value;
            var valueFourteen = document.getElementById('valueFourteen').value;
            var valueFifteen = document.getElementById('valueFifteen').value;
            var valueSixteen = document.getElementById('valueSixteen').value;
            var valueSeventeen = 0;//document.getElementById('valueSeventeen').value;
            var valueEightteen = document.getElementById('valueEightteen').value;
            var valueNineteen = document.getElementById('valueNineteen').value;
            var valueTwenty = document.getElementById('valueTwenty').value;
            var valueTwentyone = document.getElementById('valueTwentyone').value;
            var valueTwentytwo = document.getElementById('valueTwentytwo').value;
            var valueTwentythree = document.getElementById('valueTwentythree').value;
            var valueTwentyfour = document.getElementById('valueTwentyfour').value;
            var valueTwentyfive = document.getElementById('valueTwentyfive').value;
            var result =
                (isNaN(valueOne) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueOne) * .7) +
                (isNaN(valueTwo) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwo) * .7) +
                (isNaN(valueThree) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueThree) * .5) +
                (isNaN(valueFour) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueFour) * .5) +
                (isNaN(valueFive) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueFive) * .5) +
                (isNaN(valueSix) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueSix)) +
                (isNaN(valueSeven) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueSeven) * .45) +
                (isNaN(valueEight) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueEight) * .45) +
                (isNaN(valueNine) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueNine) * .45) +
                (isNaN(valueTen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTen) * 3) +
                (isNaN(valueEleven) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueEleven) * 3) +
                (isNaN(valueTwelve) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwelve) * .6) +
                (isNaN(valueThirteen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueThirteen) * .47) +
                (isNaN(valueFourteen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueFourteen) * .65) +
                (isNaN(valueFifteen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueFifteen) * .55) +
                (isNaN(valueSixteen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueSixteen)) +
                (isNaN(valueSeventeen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueSeventeen)) +
                (isNaN(valueEightteen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueEightteen)) +
                (isNaN(valueNineteen) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueNineteen) * 1.5) +
                (isNaN(valueTwenty) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwenty) * .55) +
                (isNaN(valueTwentyone) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwentyone) * 3) +
                (isNaN(valueTwentytwo) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwentytwo) * 3) +
                (isNaN(valueTwentythree) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwentythree) * 3) +
                (isNaN(valueTwentyfour) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwentyfour) * .5) +
                (isNaN(valueTwentyfive) ? 0 : parseFloat(valueTwentyfive) * 1.5);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Power Needed: ' + result + ' amps.';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: There is no "valueSeventeen" text box.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly and it does look a lot better! Im sure that this code also loads much faster as well within the browser lol Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick you closed the parentheses after `valueFour`. Move that to the end of the onclick.

Additionally, there is no input with id `valueSeventeen`.

Fixing those made it work for me.